# The maximal eigenvalue of a symmetric Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, toeplitz-operators

Let $0\le x\le 1$ be a   real number. Denote by $A_n(x)=(a_{ij})$ the $n$ by $n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}=x^{|i-j|}$ and let $\lambda_n(x)$ be the maximal eigenvalue of $A_n(x)$.

> Is there any formula for $\lambda_n(x)$?

I am particularly interested in the following question.

> Let $y_n$ be such that $\lambda_n(y_n)=\frac{n}4$. What is the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (y_n)^n$$ if the limit exists?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68099/

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: thank you for the link.

Answer (score 6):

Using the results in [pages 59-63 of Rosenblum and Rovnyak](http://books.google.com/books?id=omZF4yM0p-0C&pg=PA62) (p. 62 in particular, and noting that your Toeplitz matrices are symmetric, hence normal, so the operator norm is what you want), it follows that $\lim_n \lambda_n(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$. The non-asymptotic behavior is probably hard, but numerics clearly indicate (and it is probably not hard to show) that $\lambda_n(1) = n$. It might be possible to combine these observations, or more detailed ones along similar lines, to get good estimates for $\lambda_n(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $\lambda_n(x)\le \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is a natural bound, because it is greater than the sum of coefficients in any row. Also you are right that $\lambda_n(1)=n$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another example of techniques used in determining the asymptotics for extrema in the spectra of a symmetric toeplitz matrix. The cited works may be of use as well.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6513v2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a closed-form expression, but there are some research results on the asymptotic behavior of eigenvalues of symmetric Toeplitz matrices: see the comments to [Spectra of a Symmetric Toeplitz Operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69419/spectra-of-a-symmetric-toeplitz-operator) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might relate it to asymptotic evaluations of certain (skew) Schur polynomials,
by interpreting your determinant via one of the [Jacobi-Trudi identities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial)
You will be interested in the second identity.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that a formula for $\lambda_n$ might exist and be reasonably nice. You might try a computer algebra system to see how far you can get. I tried for up to $n=8$ and still was getting exact answers (for each eigenvalue) for unknown $x$, cf.
https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/42c646bc-c7fc-41d8-b50d-efc995e3cd08/files/toeplitz.sagews

Comment: I take this back: from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68099/diagonalizing-a-certain-real-and-symmetric-toeplitz-matrix it is seen that apparently for $n\geq 9$ there cannot be an explicit formula.